# Docker API: use path as image build context

Tags: docker, docker-api

As I understand from [Docker API reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ImageBuild) if I have a build context for my new image, I have to create a tarball and send an URI via `remote` param. It's really inconvenient for me because I already have everything on the same host as the docker daemon. Is it possible somehow to use a PATH the same way you do with docker CLI?

```
docker built -t myimage:tag PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would post the tar'd files as e.g. explained here: [Build image using dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995388/build-image-using-dockerfile). In this case, you don't need a `remote` param at all. It's easy with curl.

If you perhaps aren't using curl and that is still inconvenient, you could run a small Docker container that serves your build files over http.

`file://` doesn't work in current versions of Docker. Maybe it'll be added at some point, but probably not. `git://` is supported.

---

(The following is more an aside, and I hope that this doesn't confuse you. I'd recommend not using this:)

Reading the source I stumbled upon some uncareful? coding that may allow you to use local git repositories if the directory name starts with `git@` and is located in the CWD of the `dockerd` daemon (which you can find out with `` ls -l /proc/`pidof dockerd`/cwd ``. It's probably `/`.). Taking this one step further, if you create a symbolic link called `git@` and point it to `/`, you can then do `git@/home/.../...` to access any other directory you need. However, this directory needs to be a git repository with everything committed.

So let's say I have a directory called `git@` in `dockerd`'s working directory and a git-committed `Dockerfile` with e.g. the contents:

```
FROM debian
CMD sleep inf
```

Then I can build that using:

```
curl http://localhost:2375/build?remote=git@
```